# How to sum items in the listbox

Tags: c#

I want to sum the items in the list box by method, and I want to print the result on label1.

[image]

**Code:**

```
void sum()
    {
       ...
    }

    int index = 0;
    string[] numbers= new string[10];


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Add Button
    {
        if (index < numbers.Length)
        {
            numbers[index] = textBox1.Text;
            listBox1.Items.Add(numbers[index++]);
        }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Sum calc button
    {
      ...
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Use a loop to go through the items in your ListBox.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that all the items in your `ListBox` are numeric types, then you can just cast the collection to `int` (or `decimal`, etc.) and get the `Sum` using `System.Linq`. Note that this will throw an exception in the `Cast()` method if the item in the list is not of the type we're trying to cast to:

```
// Add integers to listbox
listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });

// Get the sum using Linq
int sum = listBox1.Items.Cast<int>().Sum();
```

If the list contains a mix of numeric types, but they can all be converted to the same type (like integers, doubles, and decimals) then we can convert them instead of cast:

```
// Initialize with an int, double, single, and decimal
listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {1, 2.1, 3.2f, 4.3m});

// Use 'Convert' instead of 'Cast' (after casting to the base object type):
decimal sum = listBox1.Items.Cast<object>().Select(Convert.ToDecimal).Sum();
```

If any of the types are non-numeric, then you have to test to see if they can be converted before getting the sum. One way to do this is to use `[numericType].TryParse` on the `item.ToString()` value to do the conversion. This method is handy because it returns `true` if the item can be converted, and sets the `out` parameter to the converted value. If you want `int` values only, use `int.TryParse`. If you want more numeric types, try `decimal.TryParse`:

```
// Initialize the array so it includes a non-numeric string type
listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {"1", 2, 3.1, 4.2f, 5.6m});

decimal sum = 0;

foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    decimal temp;
    if (decimal.TryParse(item.ToString(), out temp))
    {
        sum += temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the UpdateLabel function to make the label value the sum.

```
    private int Sum()
    {
        var sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if(int.TryParse(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), out var n))
            {
                sum += n;
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }

    private void UpdateLabel()
    {
        label1.text = Sum().ToString();
    }
```